# Using pull() from dplyr after reading data with haven::read_sas keeps attributes. How to avoid?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-haven

I am working with several data sets that originally come as a `.sas7bdat` file.

Initially, I loaded all files using the `sas7bdat` package but I am now convinced that the `haven` package can do a better and quicker job.

However, newly loaded data with `haven::read_(sas)` seems to behave differently compared to `sas7bdat::read.sas7bdat()` when using `pull()` from `dplyr`:

```r
library("haven")
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library("sas7bdat")

data.sas7 <- sas7bdat::read.sas7bdat(system.file("examples", "iris.sas7bdat", package = "haven"))
data.sas7 %>% summarise(mean = mean(Petal_Length)) %>% pull
#> [1] 3.758

data.haven <- haven::read_sas(system.file("examples", "iris.sas7bdat", package = "haven"))
data.haven %>% summarise(mean = mean(Petal_Length)) %>% pull
#> [1] 3.758
#> attr(,"format.sas")
#> [1] "BEST"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As can be seen from the example above the `attr()` are printed as well when data is loaded using `haven`. This in not practical when I want, for instance, print the outcome in an `rmarkdown`.

**My question is: how can I avoid the attribute being printed when using `pull()` form `dplyr` when data is loaded with `haven`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's reproduce similar data:

```
iris2 <- iris
attr(iris2$Petal.Length,"format.sas") <- "BEST"
iris2 %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
  pull
# [1] 3.758
# attr(,"format.sas")
# [1] "BEST"
```

Then see the first line I use here, it strips the attribute `"format.sas"` of all columns :

```
iris2 %>% 
  mutate_all(`attr<-`,"format.sas", NULL) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
  pull
# [1] 3.758
```

If you want to remove all attributes:

```
iris2 %>% 
  mutate_all(`attributes<-`, NULL) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
  pull

# [1] 3.758
```

Comment: Just for the beauty of the code, you can use `iris2 %>% mutate_all(~{attributes(.x) <- NULL; .x})`, the condensed version of `iris2 %>% mutate_all(function(x){attributes(x) <- NULL; x })`. I personally find it a little more understandable.

Comment: or define a function `strip_attributes()` that removes all by default, aor the given ones if any